# ServiceHost.Close not returning within…

Tags: wcf

Calling `ServiceHost.Close()` allows host instance to gracefully exit by allowing calls in progress to complete, while refusing future client calls. Assuming `ServiceHost.CloseTimeout` is set to 10 seconds, then `ServiceHost` instance will block for 10 seconds while waiting for `Close()` to return

a) What happens if `Close()` doesn’t return within 10 seconds? Will `ServiceHost` instance forcefully shut itself down without throwing any exceptions?

b) What are common scenarios where `Close()` doesn’t return within specified time? Perhaps when client-call in progress is still being processed?

thank you

**REPLY:**

I’m confused. In your example service host does wait for operation to complete, but in my example it doesn’t, since `Console.WriteLine("GetDog completed");` ( called within `GetDog()`) doesn’t get executed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDogs
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetDog();
    }

    public class Animals : IDogs
    {
        public string GetDog()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            Console.WriteLine("GetDog completed"); // this doesn't get executed
            return "dalmatian";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServiceHost host1 = 
                new ServiceHost(typeof(Animals),new Uri("http://localhost:8000"));
            host1.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDogs), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Dogs");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            host1.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

            host1.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                "mex");

            host1.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
            host1.Close();
        }
    }
```

BTW – why isn’t exception thrown within the main thread ( which calls `host.Close()`)? Instead it is thrown from a thread that executes `Service.doFoo()`?!

Comment: Are you sure that call reaches GetDog() method? Add a Write call to the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1):

a) It will throw a TimeoutException.

b) It may time out if you've overriden `OnClosing`, `OnClose(TimeSpan)` or `OnClosed` with something time-consuming. And, yes, according to this [list of errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738635%28VS.90%29.aspx), it will wait for the operation to be dispatched. See `SfxCloseTimedOutWaitingForDispatchToComplete`. Need to test it though.

**Update**. Well, apparently, that is true. The service host will wait for operations to complete before it changes the host State, although client connections will be aborted immediately. Here's the code I used to test this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Server
        string baseUri = "http://localhost:8080/test/";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(new Service(), new Uri(baseUri));
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, baseUri);
        host.Closed += ((sender, arguments) => Console.WriteLine("Closed"));
        host.Open();

        //Client
        ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(endpoint);
        new Action(() => 
        {
            try
            {
                factory.CreateChannel().DoFoo();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }).BeginInvoke(null, null);

        //Making sure request has reached the server
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        host.Close();
    }
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoFoo started");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("DoFoo finished");
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoFoo();
}
```

Output:

```
        DoFoo started
    An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8080/tes
    t/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protoco
    l. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
     (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
    DoFoo finished
    Closed
```

Comment: A - So setting ServiceHost.CloseTimeout property has the same effect as setting the timeout parameter for ServiceHost.Close(TimeSpan timeout)? B - “And, yes, according to this list of errors, it will wait for the operation to be dispatched. See SfxCloseTimedOutWaitingForDispatchToComplete” Are you implying that if client-call is still being processed when the timeout occurs, then Close() waits for client-call processing to be completed ( however long it may take ) and result is sent back to client, and only then does it throw an error?

Comment: a) Yes, I think so. It will be used when you call parameterless `Close()` overload. b) See update to my answer.

Comment: "Are you sure that call reaches GetDog() method? Add a Write call to the beginning of the method." Call does reach GetDog(). I've added a Write call to the beginning of GetDog() and it got executed